# uniq -c without additional spaces

Tags: shell, uniq

Is there an option in uniq -c (or an alternative) that doesn't add additional whitespaces around the count number? Currently I generally pipe it through sed, like so:

```
sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]*\) /\1 /'
```

But this seems kinda redundant, particularly given how frequently I have to do this.

Comment: Provide sample output that bothers you (raw and converted) or a sample input file.

Comment: Also, this really depends on your final usage. There may be a better way of doing it depending on what you really need (XY problem).

Comment: Short answer is no. The whitespace is there because the numerical fields are right-justified, so a field-width large enough to hold a reasonably large count was selected.

Comment: Make a small script or function called `johniq` calling `uniq -c | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]*\) */\1 /'`.

Comment: @WalterA , yeah that's probably the best solution, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to make the sed command as short as possible with

```
sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//'
```

If you have GNU grep, you can also use the -P flag:

```
sort | uniq -c | grep -Po '\d.*'
```

(Do not use `awk '{$1=$1};1'`, it will trim more than you want)

When you need this often, you can make a function or script calling

```
sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//'
```

or only

```
uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//'
```